# Cannot add foreign key constraint error when running rails migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a users table in my MySQL database. In my rails 4 application I created a Permission model as follows:

```
rails g model Permission user:references privilege:references
```

When I run the migration for creating the permissions table, the table does get created in the database, but I get the following error:

```
== 20170223171936 CreatePermissions: migrating ================================
-- create_table(:permissions)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred:

Mysql2::Error: Cannot add foreign key constraint: ALTER TABLE `permissions` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_d9cfa3c257`
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
  REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
```

Since the users table already exists, I'm puzzled as to why the foreign key creation fails in the permissions table. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 16):

I fixed this. The column type of `users_id` in the generated permissions table was int(11), and that of the `id` column in the users table was int(11) unsigned. **TLDR:** The data type of the foreign key column and that of the referenced column should be the same.

You can see the column types by running `show full columns from <table_name>`. You can also see the exact reason why adding the foreign key fails by running `show engine innodb status`.

I created a migration to remove the unsigned property from the `id` for the users table, and now that the column types were aligned, the foreign key addition worked!

Comment: Experienced a similar problem with Rails 5.1, where primary keys are now BigInts. I added a foreign key with `add_column(:projects, :price_list_id, :integer, null: false)` and when I tried to add the foreign key the migration bombed. I needed `add_column(:projects, :price_list_id, :bigint, null: false)` for the foreign key so that they matched.

Answer (score 13):

The way I've been handling this since we upgraded to Rails 5.2:

I go ahead and create the migration 
`rails g model Example user:references`

Then, before I run the migration, I open the migration file and edit `t.references :user, foreign_key: true` to `t.references :user, foreign_key: true, type: :integer`

Then running `rake db:migrate` should run successfully and add the foreign key for you.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that rails was looking up the wrong table for the relationship I was trying to create. I was creating a self referential table and was running this in my migration:

`add_reference :categories, :linked_category, foreign_key: true`

I wanted the column name to be linked_category_id.

What was happening was that rails was looking for a linked_categories table, which didnt exist:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`linked_category_id`)
  REFERENCES `linked_categories` (`id`)
```

The solution was to set which table the foreign key should reference:

`add_reference :categories, :linked_category, foreign_key: { to_table: :categories }`

Answer (score 0):

I often run into this problem because there is a missing index on the column targeted by the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
rails g model Permission user:integer:index privilege:integer:index
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who run into this error when adding the index to an EXISTING table that CONTAINS DATA:

1. Backup the table data (i.e. create a dump file), in order to be able to reverse everything if needed
2. `TRUNCATE` the table (empties and resets it completely)
3. Run the migration again (with the table being empty).

(When the migration wants to add the index and finds records in the table, it will want to add the index data for these records. But it can't because wasn't given the data. So when there are no records present, it will not attempt to do this - thus no error.)

Answer (score -3):

set the foreign_key to false --> 
t.references :user, foreign_key: false

reset the database --> rails db:migrate:reset,

set back the foreign_key to true --> 
t.references :user, foreign_key: true

then migrate the DB --> rails db:migrate

Comment: I kept running into this error over and over. Sure, some of the fixes above worked, but having this error keep popping up, I decided to give this one a shot. Low and behold, it worked!

Comment: This is a solution for fixing it locally but you're going to have a bad time running this in production.

Comment: Locally this is indeed the only solution that is working.